# IDLE (Python 3.4) - Execute a script on launch

Tags: python, linux, shell, raspberry-pi, python-idle

I've been spending the last week or so creating a simple touch friendly GUI in python3.4 (on the raspberry pi). Now I setup python to run my script on launch, but I ran into the problem, that I couldn't open other programs from within my program (such as the web browser or calculator). However if I use IDLE to execute the script and not the standard python program in the terminal, opening other programs from my scrip works! I already created a .sh file that runs when the Linux Gui starts, which opens up my script in IDLE, however it only opens the file and doesn't execute it.

So now here is my question: Can I create a .sh script, which opens IDLE and runs a python script in the IDLE console (I already tried the exec command when launching idle with no results)

Right now this is my command, which should execute the loaded file, but only loads it for some reaseon:

```
sudo idle3 -c exec(open('/path/to/my/file.py').read())
```

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: I am puzzled that running other programs from within your program would only work when your program is run by IDLE.  It could be a path issue, or it could be a bug within your program, python on the raspberry-pi, or even IDLE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Use Idle's cli options

You have a few options, of which the best one is to use the `-r` option. From `man idle`:

```
   -r file
          Run script from file.
```

This will however only open the *interpreter* window. Since you also want the editor, this will do pretty much exactly what you describe:

```
idle3 '/path.to/file.py'  & idle3 -r '/path.to/file.py'
```

The *startup* command you need is then:

```
/bin/bash -c "idle3 '/path/to/file.py'  & idle3 -r '/path/to/file.py'"
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

The command you tried will not work, since [here](https://linux.die.net/man/2/idle), we can read:

> Only process 0 may call idle(). Any user process, even a process with superuser permission, will receive EPERM.

Therefore, we depend on cli options of `idle`, which luckily provide an option :)

---

#### Alternatively

Another option would be to open the file with `idle3` wait for the window to appear and simulate <kbd>F5</kbd>:

```sh
/bin/bash -c "idle3 '/path/to/file.py'  & sleep 3 && xdotool key F5"
```

This would need [xdotool](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=xdotool&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD%208.1-RELEASE%20and%20Ports&format=html) to be installed on your system.

An advanced version of this wrapper would open the file with `idle`, subsequently check if the new window exists, is focussed and simulate <kbd>F5</kbd> with `xdotool`.

These would however be the dirty options, which we luckily don't need :).

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed! :D